# Function declaration must have a name

Tags: java, android

I have strings of codes in my `Main.Activity.kt` of Android studio but I keep getting the error message "Function declaration must have a name: Unresolved reference"

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/**
 * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
 */
public void submitOrder(View view) {
    display(2);
    displayPrice(2*5);
}

/**
 * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
 */
private void display(int number) {
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
    quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace (but this is not what you want) `displayPrice(2*5);` with `display(2*5);` (only to solve the unreferenced error, then you will see the price instead of the quantity). Also to display the price you need create the method :

`private void displayPrice(int number) { 
    \\ do price print.
}`

The method`displayPrice` is undeclared so that's why bad reference error appears.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `displayPrice(2*5);` function so replace `displayPrice(2*5);` to `display(2*5);` otherwise create function with name `displayPrice(int number);`

Answer (score 0):

Your file has a .kt extension indicating its kotlin but only contains java code!

Either migrate it to kotlin or use a .java file for it.

Also drop the "." between "Main" and "Activity"

So you either go for:

MainActivity.java containing your java code

OR

MainActivity.kt containing kotlin code (recommended)